# What is the relationship between an Angular 1.X controller and directive

Tags: angularjs

I am NOT asking what the difference between the two is, I'm wondering how they work together when there is both a directive and controller for a component.

Comment: It isn't clear what you mean. A component *is* a directive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*I'm not sure why you got down-voted on this as I think it's a relevant question about one of the less clear aspects of angular 1.x.*

## exposing directive APIs

One of the prime reasons to set up a directive with a controller is to expose a directive's API to other directives.  A good example of this is `ngModel` and the `ngModelController`.  Many custom directives need access to the `ngModel` that's also declared on or above where the custom directive is declared.  You see this in the directive definition via:

```
{ require:'^ngModel' }
```

This is actually saying *this* custom directive needs to access the APIs available on the `ngModelController` to do additional work.  For instance, you want a directive to do some custom parsing or formatting on a particular ngModel.  In my app, I kept getting errors for date strings that came back from the server.  I created this custom directive to handle the error and format the string properly (this is coffeescript btw):

```
.directive 'dateString', [
()->
    {
        priority: 10
        require: 'ngModel'
        link: ($scope, elem, attrs, ngModel)->
            ngModel.$formatters.push (val)-> new Date(val)
    }
]
```

If there were no `ngModelController`, I would not have access to the APIs to add a new formatter function.

So in conclusion, we might create directive controllers to provide APIs for other directives that may operate on the same UI element.

## classic controller role

In order to be within the spirit and intent of Angular, using a controller to expose APIs to the template is better than trying to use a jquery implementation.  In other words, it's better to do this:

**directive w. controller**

```
controller: function($scope){ 
    $scope.doSomething = function(){ ... }
},
template: '<div><button ng-click="doSomething()">Click Me</button></div>'
```

vs something like this

**directive w. jquery-like implementation**

```
link: function($scope, elem, attrs){
     elem('button').bind('click', function(){ ... })
},
template: '<div><button>Click Me</button></div>'
```