# In AngularJS how to access multiple child scopes from parent scope

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a parent `zone builder` controller which has multiple `US States` that can have several zip codes within each state.

Here is a breakdown of the basics of the format:

BUILDER CONTROLLER

```
app.controller("builderController", function($scope, $http, $rootScope, $timeout) {
  $scope.zones = [];
});
```

ZIP CONTROLLER

```
app.controller("zipController", function($scope, $http, $rootScope, $timeout) {

  $scope.zipCodes = [];

  $scope.addZipCode = function() {
    $scope.zipCodes.push({code: '', distance: '25mi'});
  }
  $scope.removeZipCode = function(index) {
    console.log(index, 'index removing');
    $scope.zipCodes.splice(index, 1);
  }

});
```

There can be `multiple zipControllers` in one `builderController` inside of the builder controller I want to come up with an object or way to iterate through all of the Zip Controllers so that I can calculate a total distance and number of zip codes used, each time one of the child controllers is updated.

What is the most efficient way to do something like this in Angular?

BASIC GOAL

So there could be 4-5 `zipController` elements in one `builderController` I want to have a variable in the `builderController` called something like `totalZipCodes` which counts the total number of zip codes in each `zipCodes` array for each controller, How would I do that with a service or factory?  Or is there another way?

Comment: I'd definitely look at using a component then. https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/component. You can pass bindings to the component of which you can keep track off in the builder controller

Answer (score 0):

Store the data in a factory and have the controller call the factory to do the calculations.

Comment: Can you provide any examples?

Comment: Here's a rough example I found: http://embed.plnkr.co/E8b5RZ/. The Factory stores all the data and has services/functions to access it. The controllers call the factory functions to add/get data.

Answer (score 0):

## a general approach

As @PrinayPanday suggested in his comment, you should use something like a component/directive to do this.  I'm prefacing this by saying I will be using the term directive and component interchangeably as I'm not sure of your constraints.  I would achieve this by doing the following:

- create a parent directive that defines a directive controller
- create child directives that require the parent directive controller
- when the child directive initializes, it will register itself with the parent controller
- use the parent controller's *list* of child directive controllers to do what you need to.

You could also use the child's scope to declare a callback on some event (such as `$onInit`) rather than defining the directive controllers.  I have answered several questions like this.  So you might find these answers to be helpful in understanding the above solution more:

- [What is the relationship between an Angular 1.X controller and directive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40382996/what-is-the-relationship-between-an-angular-1-x-controller-and-directive/40383416#40383416)
- [Angular: Looking for an explanation on custom directive syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37817794/angular-looking-for-an-explanation-on-custom-directive-syntax/37820304#37820304)

#### specific to your needs

As I'm rereading your question, I have to ask if there may not be a better way to solve this by sharing the data in a service/model rather than needing custom directives?

Comment: I don't really understand services, or what their purpose or function is

Comment: Services are *Singleton* objects that you can inject into other angular entities. You can create a service that has an **add/del** API for your child components. You can also make a **getList** API so that the parent controller can access this as well.  Given that you're new to angular, I would take this approach over the directive/component route in my answer.

Comment: Is there anyway to get a simple example, that doesn't really make sense.  I want to count the total number of valid zip codes across all controllers